# Strange email after installing a package

Tags: managed-package, package-install

I installed a managed package on a scratch org and a little later got a "successful install" email that also stated:

> Some components, such as custom objects, custom report types, and workflow rules, must be activated using the package deploy process, before they are available to your organization

What does this mean? I've never heard of a need to activate custom objects and don't know what the "package deploy process" is other than installation (which has successfully completed).

Any ideas?

Comment: I remember there is such a property for custom object as "deployment state", or something like that. It's configured in object settings and is "deployed" by default. Try checking that thing. Not sure if it's applicable to managed packages though